# Finding the closest pentagonal number,  given a positive integer, S where S ≥ 1

Tags: r, function, math, number-theory

I need to create a function in R that takes as input an integer, S ≥ 1 and returns as output the pentagonal number which is closest to S.The output of my function should be the pentagonal number  which satisfies |−|≤|−| for all positive integers m.

However if I could get two different pentagonal numbers which happens when the integer, s is literally in the middle of them. Then it doesn't matter which one it takes (greater or lesser value) which is like when S is 17 and the pentagonal number closest to 17 is 12 and 22 so it can take either one.

Here is the following code that I have created which is used to find the pentagonal number  for a given positive integer, n:

```
P_n=function(n){
x=(3*n^2-n)/2
if(n == 0){
return (0)
}else{
return(x)
}
}
```

After writing the code to find pn, I am now stuck with finding the closest pentagonal number for integer, s. I know that the main idea is to distinguish Pm and Pn using ceiling and floor function but I don't really know how to link it to the equation  |−|≤|−|.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
P_n <- Vectorize(function(n)   max((3 * n^2 - n) / 2, 0))
k <- floor((1 + sqrt(1 + 24 * x)) / 6)
(n <- k - 1 + which.min(abs(P_n(c(k,k+1)) - x)))
```

---

## Example 1

```
> x <- 18

> k <- floor((1 + sqrt(1 + 24 * x)) / 6)

> (n <- k - 1 + which.min(abs(P_n(c(k,k+1)) - x)))
[1] 4
```

## Example 2

```
> x <- 17

> k <- floor((1 + sqrt(1 + 24 * x)) / 6)

> (n <- k - 1 + which.min(abs(P_n(c(k,k+1)) - x)))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Hi there, I would like to ask the reasoning behind this line of code
'P_n <- Vectorize(function(n)   max((3 * n^2 - n) / 2, 0))'. What did Vectorize do to my function P_n?

Comment: Also i think you misunderstood the question. I wanted to find    which is the closest pentagonal number to my integer S, what you gave me was the nth integer of pentagonal number  that happens to be the closest to S

Comment: @ChenWin Then you can use `P_n(n)` to obtain the desired output. The vectorized `P_n` allows you to pass a vector, not just a scalar.

Comment: Much appreciated for the reply. May I know what does "passing a vector" is supposed to do? Sorry I'm relatively new to R

Comment: @DaddySinged  In my function `P_n`, you can use `P_n(c(1,2,3,4,))`. But in your original `P_n`, you will have error when you pass `c(1,2,3,4)` to `P_n`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops, just solve following problem:

For input S find minimum n such that: 3n^2-n-2S >= 0

By doing that you get your two candidates:

```
n <- (1 + sqrt(1 + 24 * S)) / 6
p1 <- P_n(floor(n))
p2 <- P_n(ceiling(n))

c(p1, p2)[which.min(c(S - p1, p2 - S))]
```

In the case when the difference is same this will prefer lower pentagonal number (because of the way `which.min` works in case of equal numbers).

Comment: Hi there I believe you have missed understood the question. I wanted to find Pn that is closest to S. So for instance (input) S = 179 , then the output should be Pn =176 since 176 is the closest pentagonal number to S. What you did instead was giving me the nth number of that pentagonal number which happens to be closest to S

Comment: and you get exactly that output. You can save it in variable if you want `pn <- c(p1, p2)[which.min(c(S - p1, p2 - S))]`

Comment: Alright, thank you! I figured that out right after I finished putting my comment *facepalm* Much appreciated for the help